# DB2 remove trailing 0 and

Tags: db2

I have BIGINT like

```
5500
10800
700
10450
10000
```

and on a select I need to divide them for 10000 and then I want to remove all ending 0 decimals.
So desidered output should be

```
0.55
1.08
0.07
1.045
1
```

I've tried with

```
rtrim (rtrim (cast (cast ((cast (column_A as float) / 10000) as decimal(31,4)) as varchar(32000)), '0'), '.')
```

for removing at first the trailing '0' and then the trailing '.' But this is what I get

```
.55
1.08
.07
1.045
1
```

What should I do for keeping the first 0 for 0.55 and 0.07? I thought rtrim was removing them only from the right...
I've tried also using

```
TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0'
```

instead of RTRIM but nothing changes.

I'm on windows with DB2 v.10.5 and IBM Data Studio 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cast (0.1 as varchar (x))` returns `.1`, not `0.1`.
But `cast (decfloat (0.1) as varchar (x))` returns `0.1`.
So try the following:

```
cast (decfloat (i) / 10000 as varchar (20))
```